# Debugging gRPC service in k8s?

Tags: web-services, kubernetes, grpc

I've set up a service in kubernetes. However, I cannot reach it over TCP. What are the next debugging steps?

- I've checked the service logs, the process has started
- I've inspected the service endpoints -- it correctly finds the pod
- I've execed bash into the service pod, however, I found Internet connection slow within service (I've checked the node IO, and it isn't the highest that's ever been). My plan was installing telnet and checking can I manually connect to service gRPC server.
- I've tried putting "0.0.0.0/50051" and "[::]:50051" as server address/port with the same results -- not working
- I've tried port-forward with the localhost and service, but it isn't working when connecting via port-forwards
- The service is, of course, tested locally, before deploying in the cloud. It works as expected.
- Kubernetes is installed on google cloud platform via their supplied engine.

For the kubernetes yaml I've setup for TCP service, and I've pretty much copy/paste/modify for another service exposing JSON REST api server. What are some next steps I can take into the debugging?

EDIT 1:

https://pastebin.com/PweEv6gc This is my kubernetes-helm config. I'm trying to reach it within the cluster. When I try to reach it outside the cluster I'm using `kubectl port-forward 50051 50051` utility.

EDIT 2:

I've tried to spin up ordinary flask web server and it works with specific pod/k8s/port configuration. This issues is related to grpc. or it's port binding.

I've used:

```
server.add_insecure_port("0.0.0.0:50051")
server.start()
```

And managed to connect via node port (10.132.0.25:31128, which I got from `kubectl get service oracle` but within the cluster it says unreachable.

EDIT 3:

I've tried the same script inside the kubernetes and my localhost.

With using 10.132.0.25:31158 (nodeport):
On my localhost it normally connects to the gRPC server.
Inside k8s, it doesn't work

with using oracle:50051
Inside k8s it doesn't work

Update:
Found the bug....it was hard. The HTTP proxy was set up, and on the tested pod I've used HTTP proxy which probably doesn't implement http/2  (tinyproxy). How can I print gRPC debug logs to get this info?

Update2: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/environment_variables.md

for gRPC better debug logs

Comment: Are you trying to connect to your service from outside the cluster? If so, you need to expose it: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/expose-external-ip-address/ . I'm not sure what did you do when you say "I've tried putting such and such as server address/port -- what exactly did you do? (modify configuration? gave those arguments to `tellnet`?)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/PweEv6gc This is my kubernetes-helm config. I'm trying to reach it within the cluster. When I try to reach it outside the cluster I'm using kubectl port-forward utility.

Comment: I'm not sure about `type: NodePort`. I have no idea what it does (I don't have it in my configuration). I typically specify `protocol` in `port` configuration, but I'm not sure if that's important. What language did you use to specify `server.add_insecure_port()...`? (also, it seems like it wants just the port, and it will bind 0.0.0.0 automatically?) If you `exec` into container, can you run there `netstat -tpln` or similar to see what ports are being used? Perhaps try to figure out the hostname of your service and bind to that name rather than 0.0.0.0?

Comment: (contd) Also, if you are trying to access the service by its name from container in the same pod - that won't work (it's a bug in Kubernetes). But you should be able to access it on `localhost`.

Comment: Oh, I see you figured it out :)